# An open set of $ \mathbb{R}^2$ without a point is not simply connected

Tags: algebraic-topology

> An open set of $ \mathbb{R}^2$ without a point is not simply connected

I need a rigorous proof of this because I only have the intuitive idea that a loop around the point can not be deformed into a point.

Comment: Do you know that $S^1$ is not simply connected?

Comment: Yes, I know that its fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @MooS The tricky part here is to show that this open set with hole contracts to $S^1$. I am not an expert so I have no obvious way in mind.

Comment: @M.Winter Its not that hard. If you could deform any curve to a point while staying in the open set minus the point, you could to the same while staying in the whole plane minus the point. Thus if the open set minus the point is simply connected the whole space minus the point is also. But this one is clearly homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $U$ be an open set and $x\in U$. Assume without loss of generality that $x=0$, the origin. We can define the continuous function

$$f:U\setminus\{0\}\to S^1, x\mapsto \frac x{\|x\|}.$$

Because $U$ is open, there is some $\epsilon>0$ so that $B(0,\epsilon)\subseteq U$. So take any closed curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to S^1$. You can embed this curve in $U\setminus\{0\}$ via $\gamma\mapsto \epsilon\gamma=:\gamma'$. If $U\setminus\{0\}$ is simply connected, there is a homotopy contracting $\gamma'$ to a point. Via $f$, this maps to a homotpy of $\gamma$ to a point in $S^1$. We know that $S^1$ is *not* simply connected, hence not every curve should be contractible. Contradiction. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

By normalizing each nonzero vector you get a retraction of the plane minus the origin to a circle.  This is a homotopy equivalence and therefore your question is equivalent to the nonsimplyconnectedness of the circle, which you say you are familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can give another explanation of this problem, but this requires some previous knowledge about a certain kind of map called a retraction, which is defined as:

> *Definition:* Suppose $X$ is a topological space, and $A$ is a subspace of $X$, and the map $r : X\rightarrow A$ is a continuous function. Then $r$ is a *retraction* if $r\circ \iota_{A} = Id_A$, where $\iota_{A} : A \rightarrow X$ is the identity map on $A$. If such a retraction function $r$ from $X$ to $A$ exists, $A$ is called a *retract* of $X$.

Then we deal with the question.

Step 1: We can denote this open set as $U$, the open set without a point is $U\setminus \{x\}$. Then by a translation and a dilation, which are all homeomorphisms, we can assume that $S^1$, the unit circle is in $U\setminus \{x\}$ and $x$ is the origin.

Step 2: It's easy to see that for any  $p\in A$, if $r : X\rightarrow A$ is any contraction, then we can use $r : X\rightarrow A$ and $\iota_{A} : A \rightarrow X$ to induce their group homomorphisms $\iota_{A\star} : \pi_1(A,p)\rightarrow \pi_1(x,p)$, which is injective and $r_{\star}:\pi_1(x,p)\rightarrow \pi_1(A,p) $, which is surjective. This is because $(r\circ \iota_{A})_{\star} =r_{\star} \circ \iota_{A\star} = (Id_A)_{\star}$, which is the identity on $\pi_1(A,p)$.

Step 3: We can easily see from step 2 that a retract of a simply connected space is simply connected since $r_{\star}:\pi_1(x,p)\rightarrow \pi_1(A,p) $ is surjective and  $\pi_1(x,p)$ is trivial. This proposition can also be seen by observing that if the retract of a space is not simply connected then the original space is not simply connected.

Step 4: Define $r: U\setminus \{x\} \rightarrow S^1$ as $r(x) = \frac{x}{\|x\Vert}$, which can be easily checked to be a retraction so that $S^1 $ is a retraction of $U\setminus \{x\}$. Then, since $S^1$ is not simply connected (you know its fundamental gruop is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$), then $U\setminus \{x\}$ is not simply connected by step 3.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest proof is noting that $$\int_\limits{|z-\star| = \varepsilon} \frac{dz}{z-\star} \neq 0.$$ If $U \setminus \star$ would be simply connected, the integral would be zero by Cauchy's integral theorem.